# How to find what is the actual url on my browser and redirect to other url?

Tags: python, http, redirect, httprequest

Well, I have a idea, I want to make a program that block all porn pages, I need to know what is the URL of a actual page for then redirect to google.com

Example, a boy use the computer and enter to the browser, then write the URL of a porn page, now I want that Python know what is the actual page, confirm if this is a porn page by the URL, and then redirect to Google for block this page.

I have heard that a module named Scapy can do this capturing the packet and modifying them and resend, and well.

But I don't know what I have to know for do this, http request or something like that, what module I can use for this?

And I have other idea that is injecting JavaScript code for know the location URL and know if is a porn page and then redirect to google.com

This is a final academic project.

Comment: That's not how these site blocking programs work. You want to block/redirect before it reaches browser.

Comment: Ok but what module i could use for do that?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do would be to set up a  [proxy server in python](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/blob/develop/proxy.py) and reconfigure browser to use that proxy. Then you can filter anything that goes through proxy.

Answer (score 0):

use the library requests:

import requests
req = requests.get('http://yoururl')
r.url

if the r.url not the same as 'http://yoururl' then its mean you have been redirected to another URL.

for more info check: [requests library][1]

Comment: also, you can use the build in method is_redirect